# grep matches between two files and convert to lower case

Tags: unix, sed, grep, tr

I need a fast and efficient approach to the following problem (I am working with many files.) But for example:

I have two files: file2

```
Hello
Goodbye
Salut
Bonjour
```

and file1

```
Hello, is it Me you're looking for?
```

I would like to find any word in file 2 that exists in file 2, and then convert that word to lower case.

I can grep the words in a file by doing:

```
grep -f file2.txt file1.txt
```

and returns

```
Hello
```

So now I want to convert to

```
hello
```

so that the final output is

```
hello, is it Me you're looking for?
```

Where if I match multiple files:

```
grep -f file2.txt *_infile.txt
```

The output will be stored in respective separate outfiles.

I know I can convert to lower case using something like tr, but I only know how to do this on every instance of an uppercase letter. I only want to convert words common between two files from uppercase to lowercase.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would solve the problem a bit differently.

First, I would mark matches in grep. `--color=always` works well, although it's somewhat cumbersome and potentially unreliable in detection. Then I would change marked matches with `sed` or `perl`:

```
grep --color=always -F -f file2.txt file1.txt | \
    perl -p -e  's/\x1b.*?\[K(.*?)\x1b.*?\[K/\L\1/g'
```

The cryptic RE matches the coloring escape sequence before the match, de-coloring escape sequence right after the match and captures everything in between into group 1. Then it applies lowercase `\L` conversion to the capture. Likely GNU sed can do the same, but probably perl is more portable.

Comment: thanks - I gave this a go, but the output after the perl script is not the original file with the desired words uncapitalized, but rather what looks like a mixture the original text and wingdings. i think the perl command is inserting special characters

Comment: It's `grep --color=always` which is inserting special characters, used as marks. `perl` is supposed to remove them and convert marked places. I have updated the (supposed) mark sequence, but I'm still not sure if it's portable enough. Could you please run `grep --color=always -f file2.txt file1.txt | head -1 | hexdump` and show the output. Perhaps, your system uses different escape sequences to colorize terminal output

Comment: fantastic this outputs correctly - I changed `U` to `L` to convert to lower case. Thanks very much.